How to Automatically Generate Input and Output Schemas in APIFlask for Multiple Entities?
I'm working on an API project using APIFlask, Flask-Marshmallow, and SQLAlchemyAutoSchema, and I'm relatively new to building APIs. My project involves generating input and output schemas for multiple entities. Currently, I have three files: models.py, routes.py, and app.py.
For example, I manually created an output API schema for a connections entity, but I have around 30 entities, and I want to avoid manually defining schemas for each one.
Is there a way to automatically generate these input and output schemas for all my entities in a single script, so I don't have to create each schema manually? Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!
Tried manually creating but it's time consuming. Looking for a way to automatically generate schemas within apiflask.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
